# How to check for API error and thow in an observable of HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I've got an API, a C# client and its API wrapper. I have a class that contains extension methods to work with the API in a flexible way.

I'm trying to handle errors now. One of those extension methods is:

```
public static IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> CheckForApiErrors(this IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> source)
{
    return source.SelectMany(message => {
        if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            return source;
        }

        var exTask = ApiException.CreateFromHttpMessage(message);

        return Observable.FromAsync(() => exTask).SelectMany(Observable.Throw<HttpResponseMessage>);
    });
}
```

This throws correctly and I can `.Catch()` on the observable later. However, all requests that pass through that method (and are successful) are replayed now.
If I call `/some_endpoint` and it succeeds, then the observable is replayed and `/some_endpoint` is called again.

I think that the faulty line is here:

```
return source.SelectMany(message => {
    if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        return source; // <-----------
    }
```

I don't really know how to throw correclty and error, I'm doubting about my SelectMany approach to check for errors and throw, but that's the only solution I've found.

I'd like to `throw` in a `Do()` to not interfere with the normal stream, but that crashes the whole app, not just the observable.

**Edit** (got a meeting, had an idea in the middle of it, must be tired this morning):

Instead of `return source;` I can do `return Observable.Return(message);`. That works, of course. But I still don't really like my approach, I still feel like there's a more elegant way to achieve that.

Comment: "but that's the only solution I've found" - it's not a solution because it causes two subscriptions to the source observable. Shlomo's nailed the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `ApiException` has signatures that look roughly like this?

```
public class ApiException
{
    public static Task<Exception> CreateFromHttpMessage(HttpResponseMessage message)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new Exception());
    }
}
```

If you were returning `Exception` instead of `Task<Exception>` it would be more straight forward. At any rate, here's some alternatives:

```
public static IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> CheckForApiErrors2(this IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> source)
{
    return source.SelectMany(message => message.IsSuccessStatusCode
        ? Observable.Return(message)
        : Observable.FromAsync(() => ApiException.CreateFromHttpMessage(message)).SelectMany(Observable.Throw<HttpResponseMessage>
    )
}

public static IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> CheckForApiErrors3(this IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> source)
{
    return source.Publish(_source => _source
        .Where(message => message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        .Merge(_source
            .Where(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            .SelectMany(message => Observable.FromAsync(() => ApiException.CreateFromHttpMessage(message)).SelectMany(Observable.Throw<HttpResponseMessage>))
        )
    );
}
```

The first alternative is pretty much the same as your code but compacted. The second one splits the code into two streams (success and failure), handles them separately, then merges them back together.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the ApiException static factory is async because it reads from the message's content (`.ReadAsStringAsync()`). Your first solution is the condensed version of my mine (in the edit). I plan that the method will get more complex, at the point that a ternary won't be enough, that's why I didn't use `Observable.If` or a ternary.
The second solution is interesting but maybe a little bit more opaque.
Accepting as answer, because at least I know now that I didn't introduced unnecessary complexity, thanks for the help!